# Google Maps JavaScript API V3 not working on localhost

Tags: php, google-maps

i m using Google map markers with info window but when run the script on the browser it shows only map image without any functionality can some one tell whether i need to generate api key for this is what i m trying to run on localhost , see the [link](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/single-infowindow/single-infowindow.html)

Comment: What did you do so far? You don't nee API keys anymore, btw

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line:

```
<script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/5/5/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: there is no such line in <script></script> but this line was in the html "cursor: url(&quot;http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur&quot;"

Comment: Please save the file using "View Generated Source" from "View Source" menu in Firebug and don't just use "File -> Save Page as.." as the page generate new script that slightly different when captured using the standard "File -> Save Page as..." action.

Answer (score -2):

Google maps (and many other client-server services) **only work via HTTP**.

Navigating to `file://C:\Users\Greg\Documents and Settings\My Documents\WEBSITES\CoolSite\Index.html` is fine for displaying the HTML, but any client-server communication will fail.

Serve the website to something like http://coolsite.localhost (note http:// rather than file://).